# Overlay swing components selectively?

Tags: java, swing

I just started learning swing, and couldn't find any clear instructions for this: I'd like to have a JLabel (which contains the background image) and, rendered on top of it, two (or perhaps more) JButtons. If I use the layout manager OverlayLayout, the buttons are rendered on top of each other.

What would be the best way to properly render the buttons on top of the label?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a JPanel that contains it's own layout manager (e.g. GridLayout)
2. Set the size of the JPanel (Assuming OverlayLayout does not size intelligently)
3. Add JButtons to that panel
4. Add that panel to the JLabel w/bgimage

Comment: Do you mean creating two separate JPanels and letting the OverLayout handle them?

Comment: @tsiki No. Create one jpanel with an appropriate LayoutManager, add your buttons to it, and add that panel to the label with the background image.

Comment: It seems fine otherwise, but the background of the buttons (JPanel) is still visible

Comment: @tsiki `panel.setOpaque(false)` ?

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Now I just have to get the layout manager to move the background image to the same direction as the buttons when resizing...

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to add them to a [JLayeredPane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JLayeredPane.html). This way you can control what layer each compoenent is added to.

Comment: Seems fine but the buttons are also images, and for some reason JLayeredPane isn't handling the images at all. It shows the normal buttons but not the ones with icons in them.

Comment: It should be the same. Can you post some code, we can see whats going on?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your exact requirement. See [Background Panel](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/background-panel/) for a couple of suggestions.